# How to increase progress bar(progress dialog) and run a task in background simultaneously?

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog

my app does heavy task so I want to show a progress bar to user and run the task in background, so user can understand that its loading.
when the background task completes hide the progress bar.
But progress bar should not take same time to reach its max, it should be dependent on users input or processing.

Answer (score 2):

Use `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask` is one of the easiest ways to implement parallelism in Android without having to deal with more complex methods like Threads. Though it offers a basic level of parallelism with the UI thread, it should not be used for longer operations (of, say, not more than 2 seconds).

`AsyncTask` has four methods do the task:

1. `onPreExecute()`
2. `doInBackground()`
3. `onProgressUpdate()`
4. `onPostExecute()`

Check [link](https://www.concretepage.com/android/android-asynctask-example-with-progress-bar) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like this, the process ends in 30 seconds. I hope it will be useful to you

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public void init() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("please wait");
    progressDialog.show();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (time < 30) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    Message message = new Message();
                    message.what = UPDATE_PROGRESS;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Message message = new Message();
            message.what = END_PROGRESS;
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }).start();
}

private static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS = 1;
private static final int END_PROGRESS = 2;
private int time;

private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case UPDATE_PROGRESS:
                progressDialog.setMessage("Time: " + time++);
                break;

            case END_PROGRESS:
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
This is the thread and handler example. But you can also create an asynctask